# Just installed windows 8 after ubuntu and I have no boot loader

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub, bootloader

I just installed windows 8 after ubuntu.  The installation was from a CD and it installed correctly, but when it asked me to restart, there is no boot loader, i.e. there is just a blinking cursor forever.  How do I get the windows 8 boot loader?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will need to repair your your grub, this is a common enough issue , follow the steps provided in [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)
Ubuntu documentation.

Comment: Yes I tried boot-repair, but when I rebooted, still the blinking cursor and nothing happened :(

Comment: are you using a ubuntu CD ? if not try repairing from a CD I have done this on and it works, if nothing works try re-installing  windows first and then ubuntu